# Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic

Estoy realizando una app en IONIC. Uso firebase para el manejo de datos. La aplicación está acabada y funciona correctamente si en firebase no hay normas. El problema viene cuando pongo normas.

He usado en ambos casos (para storage y database) la misma regla de momento.

allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null.

Por supuesto, nada más se inicia la aplicación hago una autenticación de usuario mediante un http request, pero después cuando hago una petición a la base de datos o al storage me dice que me faltan privilegios.

A esto entiendo qué es que realmente no hago una solicitud registrado y de ahí la falta de privilegios.

Es obvio que se me escapan muchas cosas de las reglas de Firebase, y me gustaría que me orientaran un poco.

Comment: para que te tome la authentificacion debes autentificarte con el login de firebase, sino firebase no sabe que estas autentificado y no tiene uid

Answer (score 0):

La instancia con que haces la Autenticación del usuario debe de ser la misma con la que llamas a Firestore, asegúrate de guardar la referencia y con eso no debes de tener problemas.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer] saludos.